# What does `return +/- ` do in python?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, unary-operator

I was going through the CPython source code and I found the following piece of code from the standard library([`ast.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ast.py#L83C1-L86)).

```py
if isinstance(node.op, UAdd):
   return + operand
else:
   return - operand
```

I tried the following in my python interpreter

```
>>> def s():
...     return + 1
...
>>> s()
1
```

But this is same as the following right?

```
def s():
    return 1
```

Can any one help me to understand what does the expression `return +`  or `return -` do in python and when we should use this?

Comment: it seems that it is just for underlining that if True we use "+" if False we use "-"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

plus and minus in this context are [unary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation). That is, they accept **a single operand**. This is in comparison to the binary operator `*` (for example) that operates on **two operands**. Evidently `+1` is just `1`. So the unary operator `+` in your return statement is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't studied the code, so I don't know for sure, but Python allows overriding [unary operator behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html):

> `__pos__(self)` Implements behavior for unary positive (e.g. +some_object)
>
> `__neg__(self)` Implements behavior for negation (e.g. -some_object)

So `operand` in your case could be an object of a class which overrides those magic methods.

This means that `return + operand` is NOT equivalent to `return operand`.

Answer (score 0):

`return + operand` is equivalent to `return operand` (if operand is a number). The only purpose I see is to insist on the fact that we do not want the opposite of `operand`.

Answer (score 0):

Both `+` and `-` can be used as unary or binary operators. In your case they are used as unary operators. `return + operand` is the same as `return operand`. We are used to see them in the form of `return +operand` or `return -operand`.